# Multithreaded job queue manager

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I need to manage CPU-heavy multitaskable jobs in an interactive application. Just as background, my specific application is an engineering design interface. As a user tweaks different parameters and options to a model,  multiple simulations are run in the background and results displayed as they complete, likely even as the user is still editing values. Since the multiple simulations take variable time (some are milliseconds, some take 5 seconds, some take 10 minutes), it's basically a matter of getting feedback displayed as fast as possible, but often aborting jobs that started previously but are now no longer needed because of the user's changes have already invalidated them. Different user changes may invalidate different computations so at any time I may have 10 different simulations running. Somesimulations have multiple parts which have dependencies (simulations A and B can be seperately computed, but I need their results to seed simulation C so I need to wait for both A and B to finish first before starting C.)

I feel pretty confident that the code-level method to handle this kind of application is some kind of multithreaded job queue. This would include features of submitting jobs for execution, setting task priorities, waiting for jobs to finish, specifying dependencies (do this job, but only after job X and job Y have finished), canceling subsets of jobs that fit some criteria, querying what jobs remain, setting worker thread counts and priorities, and so on. And multiplatform support is very useful too.

These are not new ideas or desires in software, but I'm at the early design phase of my application where I need to make a choice about what library to use for managing such tasks. I've written my own crude thread managers in the past in C (I think it's a rite of passage) but I want to use modern tools to base my work on, not my own previous hacks.

The first thought is to run to [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) but I'm not sure it's what I want. OpenMP is great for parallelizing at a fine level, automatically unrolling loops and such. While multiplatform, it also invades your code with #pragmas. But mostly it's not designed for managing large tasks.. especially cancelling pending jobs or specifying dependencies. Possible, yes, but it's not elegant.

I noticed that [Google Chrome uses such a job manager for even the most trivial tasks.](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-google-chrome-stores-passwords) The design goal seems to be to keep the user interaction thread as light and nimble as possible, so anything that can get spawned off asynchronously, should be. From looking at the Chrome source this doesn't seem to be a generic library, but it still is interesting to see how the design uses asynchronous launches to keep interaction fast. This is getting to be similar to what I'm doing.

There are a still other  options:

[Surge.Act:](http://members.gamedev.net/Rivorus/surge/html/index.html) a Boost-like library for defining jobs. It builds on OpenMP, but does allow chaining of dependencies which is nice. It doesn't seem to feel like it's got a manager that can be queried, jobs cancelled, etc. It's a stale project so it's scary to depend on it.

[Job Queue](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/multi_threaded_job_queue.aspx) is quite close to what I'm thinking of, but it's a 5 year old article, not a supported library.

[Boost.threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) does have nice platform independent synchronization but that's not a job manager. [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) has very clean designs for task launching, but again not a full manager for chaining tasks. (Maybe I'm underestimating POCO though).

So while there are options available, I'm not satisfied and I feel the urge to roll my own library again. But I'd rather use something that's already in existence. Even after searching (here on SO and on the net) I haven't found anything that feels right, though I imagine this must be a kind of tool that is often needed, so surely there's some community library or at least common design.
On SO there's been some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501/thread-pool-for-executing-arbitrary-tasks-with-different-priorities) about [job queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125812/managing-threadpool-starvation-within-a-multithreaded-work-queue-processor), but nothing that seems to fit.

My post here is to ask you all what existing tools I've missed, and/or how you've rolled your own such multithreaded job queue.

Answer (score 18):

We had to build our own job queue system to meet requirements similar to yours ( UI thread must always respond within 33ms, jobs can run from 15-15000ms ), because there really was nothing out there that quite met our needs, let alone was performant.

Unfortunately our code is about as proprietary as proprietary gets, but I can give you some of the most salient features:

- We start up one thread per core at the beginning of the program. Each pulls work from a global job queue. Jobs consist of a function object and a glob of associated data (really an elaboration on a func_ptr and void *). Thread 0, the fast client loop, isn't allowed to work on jobs, but the rest grab as they can.
- The job queue itself ought to be a lockless data structure, such as a [lock-free singly linked list](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1377030.1377094) (Visual Studio [comes with one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360(VS.85).aspx)). Avoid using a mutex; contention for the queue is surprisingly high, and grabbing mutexes is costly.
- Pack up all the necessary data for the job into the job object itself -- avoid having pointer from the job back into the main heap, where you'll have to deal with contention between jobs and locks and all that other slow, annoying stuff. For example, all the simulation parameters should go into the job's local data blob. The results structure obviously needs to be something that outlives the job: you can deal with this either by a) hanging onto the job objects even after they've finished running (so you can use their contents from the main thread), or b) allocating a results structure specially for each job and stuffing a pointer into the job's data object. Even though the results themselves won't live in the job, this effectively gives the job exclusive access to its output memory so you needn't muss with locks.
- Actually I'm simplifying a bit above, since we need to choreograph exactly which jobs run on which cores, so each core gets its own job queue, but that's probably unnecessary for you.

Comment: would you mind explain a bit on "to choreograph exactly which jobs run on which cores, so each core gets its own job queue", what's the reason, is it for processor affinity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)?

Comment: @athos It's the other way around: processor affinity is how we say which job runs on which core.   We need to choreograph things precisely so that the two realtime threads are able to run continually on their cores without any risk of preemption, while other jobs get assigned to specific hardware cores in ways that maximize cache locality, hyperthreading efficiency, etc.  We develop for a fixed hardware platform so can optimize very tightly.

Answer (score 5):

I rolled my own, based on Boost.threads. I was quite surprised by how much bang I got from writing so little code. If you don't find something pre-made, don't be afraid to roll your own. Between Boost.threads and your experience since writing your own, it might be easier than you remember.

For premade options, don't forget that [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) is licensed very friendly, so you may be able to roll your own generic library around its code.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft is working on a set of technologies for the next Version of Visual Studio 2010 called the Concurrency Runtime, the Parallel Pattern Library and the Asynchronous Agents Library which will probably help.  The Concurrency Runtime will offer policy based scheduling, i.e. allowing you to manage and compose multiple scheduler instances (similar to thread pools but with affinitization and load balancing between instances), the Parallel Pattern Library will offer task based programming and parallel loops with an STL like programming model.  The Agents library offers an actor based programming model and has support for building concurrent data flow pipelines, i.e. managing those dependencies described above. Unfortunately this isn't released yet, so you can read about it on our [team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/nativeconcurrency) or watch some of the videos [on channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Parallel+Computing+Platform/) there is also a very large CTP that is available for download as well.

If you're looking for a solution today, Intel's Thread Building Blocks and boost's threading library are both good libraries and available now. [JustSoftwareSolutions](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/) has released an implementation of std::thread which matches the C++0x draft and of course OpenMP is widely available if you're looking at fine-grained loop based parallelism.

The real challenge as other folks have alluded to is to correctly identify and decompose work into tasks suitable for concurrent execution (i.e. no unprotected shared state), understand the dependencies between them and minimize the contention that can occur on bottlenecks (whether the bottleneck is [protecting shared state](http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/214100002) or ensuring the dispatch loop of a work queue is low contention or lock-free)... and to do this without scheduling implementation details leaking into the rest of your code.

-Rick

Answer (score 3):

Would something like [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/index.html) be useful to you? It's based on boost::threads and basically implements a simple thread task queue that passes worker functions off to the pooled threads.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at  [Flow-Based Programming](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/)  - it is based on data chunks streaming between asynchronous components. There are Java and C# versions of the driver, plus a number of precoded components.  It is intrinsically multithreaded - in fact the only single-threaded code is within the components, although you can add timing constraints to the standard scheduling rules.   Although it may be at too fine-grained a level for what you need, there may be stuff here you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for near the same requirements. I'm working on a game with 4x-ish mechanics and scheduling different parts of what gets done almost exploded my brain. I have a complex set of work that needs to get accomplished at different time resolutions, and to a different degree of actual simulation depending on what system/region the player has actively loaded. This means as the player moves from system to system, I need to load a system to the current high resolution simulation, offload the last system to a lower resolution simulation, and do the same for active/inactive regions of systems. The different simulations are big lists of population, political, military, and economic actions based on profiles of each entity. I'm going to try to describe my issue and my approach so far and I hope it's useful at describe an alternative for you or someone else. The rough outline of the structure I'm building will use the following:

1. [cpp-taskflow](https://github.com/cpp-taskflow/cpp-taskflow) (A Modern C++ Parallel Task Programming Library) I'm going to make a library of modules that will be used as job construction parts. Each entry will have an API for initializing and destruction as well as pointers for communication. I'm hoping to write it in a way that they will be nest-able using the cpp-taskflow API to set-up all the dependencies at job creation time, but provide a means of live adjustment and having a kill-switch available. Most of what I'm making will be decision trees of state machines, or state machines of behavior trees so the job data structure will be settings and states of time-resolution tagged data pointing to actual stats and object values.
2. [FlatBuffers](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers) I'm looking to use this library to build a "job list entry" as well as an "object wrapper" system. Each entry in the job queues will be a flatbuffer object describing the work needed done(settings for the module), as well as containing the data(or shared pointers to the data) for the work that needs done. The object storage flatbuffers will contain the data that represents entity tables. For me, most of the actual data will me arrays that need deciding/working on. I'm also looking to use flatbuffers as a communication/control channel between threads. I'm torn on making a master "router" thread all the others communicate through, or each one containing their own, and having some mechanism of discovery.
3. [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) Since only the active regions/systems need higher resolution work done, some of the background job lists the game will create(for thousands of systems and their entities) will be pretty large and long lived. 100's of thousands - millions of jobs(big in my mind), each requiring an unknown amount of time to complete. In my case, I don't care when they get done, as long as they all do(long campains). I plan on each thread getting a table of an in-memory sqlite db as a job queue. Each entry will contain a blob of flatbuffer work, a pointer to a buffer to notify upon completion, a pointer to a control buffer for updates, and other fields decorating the job item(location, data ranges, priority) that will get filled as the job entry makes new jobs, and as the items are consumed into the database. This give me a way I can create relational ties between jobs and simply construct queries if I need to re-work/update jobs, remove them and their dependencies, or update/re-order priorities or dependencies. All this being used in an sqlite db also means that at any time I can dump the whole thing to disk and reload it later, or switch to attaching to and processing it from disk. Additionally, this gives me access to a lot of search and ordering algorithmic work I'd normally need a bunch of different types of containers for. Being able to use SQL queries gives me a lot of options to process the jobs.

The communication queue(as a db) is what I'm torn as to whether I should make access via the corresponding thread(each thread contains it's own messaging db, and the module API has locks/mutex abstracted for access), or have all updates, adds/removes, and communication via some master router thread into one large db. I have no idea which will give me the least headaches as far as mutexing and locks. I got a few days into making a monster spaghetti beast of shared pointers to  sbuffer pools and lookup tables, so each thread had it's own buffer in, and separate out buffers. That's when I decided to just offload the giant list keeping to sqlite. Then I thought, why not just feed the flatbuffer objects of everything else into tables.

Having almost everything in a db means from each module, I can write sql statements that represent the view of the data I need to work on as well as pivot on the fly as to how the data is worked on. Having the jobs themselves in a db means I can do the same for them as well. SQLite has multi-threading access, so using it as a Multithreaded job queue manager shouldn't be too much of a stretch.

In summary, Cpp-Taskflow will allow you to setup complicated nested loops with dependency chaining and job-pool multithreading. Out of the box it comes with most of the structure you need. FlatBuffers will allow you to create job declarations and object wrappers easy to feed into stream-buffers as one unit of work and pass them between job threads, and SQLite will allow you to tag and queue the stream-buffer jobs into blob entries in a way that should allow adding, searching, ordering, updating, and removal with minimal work on your end. It also makes saving and reloading a breeze. Snapshots and roll-backs should also be doable, you just have to keep your mind wrapped around the order and resolution of events for the db.

Edit: Take this with a grain of salt though, I found your question because I'm trying to accomplish what Crashworks described. I'm thinking of using affinity to open long living threads and have the master thread run the majority of the Cpp-Taskflow hierarchy work, feeding jobs to the others. I've yet to use the sqlite meothod of job-queue/control communication, that's just my plan so far.

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost::future](http://braddock.com/~braddock/future/) (but see also this [discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.announce/220) and [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2561.html)) which looks like a really nice foundation for parallelism (in particular it seems to offer excellent support for C-depends-on-A-and-B type situations).

I looked at OpenMP a bit but (like you) wasn't convinced it would work well for anything but Fortran/C numeric code.  Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks) looked more interesting to me.

If it comes to it, it's not too hard to [roll your own](http://voluminium.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/voluminium/trunk/libcelebritas/) on top of boost::thread.
[Explanation: a thread [farm](http://voluminium.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/voluminium/trunk/libcelebritas/farm.h?view=markup) (most people would call it a pool) draws work from a thread-safe [queue](http://voluminium.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/voluminium/trunk/libcelebritas/queue.h?view=markup) of functors (tasks or jobs).  See the [tests](http://voluminium.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/voluminium/trunk/libcelebritas/farm_test.cpp?view=markup) and [benchmark](http://voluminium.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/voluminium/trunk/libcelebritas/farm_bench.cpp?view=markup) for examples of use.  I have some extra complication to (optionally) support tasks with priorities, and the case where executing tasks can spawn more tasks into the work queue (this makes knowing when all the work is actually completed a bit more problematic; the references to "pending" are the ones which can deal with the case).  Might give you some ideas anyway.]

Comment: Excellent. boost::future looks extremely similar to POCO's ActiveResults (http://pocoproject.org/poco/docs/Poco.ActiveResult.html). Again that's not a work queue manager, but a great tool nonetheless.

Boost:thread's base does feel like the best low level toolkit for making a custom manager.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to look at [Intel Thread Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).  I beleave it does what you want and with version 2 it's Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of distributed resource managers out there.  The software that meets nearly all of your requirements is [Sun Grid Engine](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/).  SGE is used on some of the worlds largest supercomputers and is in active development.

There's also similar solutions in [Torque](http://www.clusterresources.com/pages/products/torque-resource-manager.php), [Platform LSF](http://www.platform.com/Products/platform-lsf), and [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/).

It sounds like you may want to roll your own but there's plenty of functionality in all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking for a C++ library (which I think you are), but Doug Lea's Fork/Join framework for Java 7 is pretty nifty, and does exactly what you want. You'd probably be able to implement it in C++ or find a pre-implemented library.

More info here:
http://artisans-serverintellect-com.si-eioswww6.com/default.asp?W1

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the punch perhaps, but take a look also at ThreadWeaver:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThreadWeaver

Comment: Link to repo: https://projects.kde.org/projects/frameworks/threadweaver/repository