# Platform-independent concurrent programming libraries for C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, parallel-processing

I am familiar with concurrent programming in Java which provides a lot of tools for this. However, C++ concurrent programming isn't so easy to start using.

What is the best way to start programming concurrently on C++? Are there any nice libraries which wrap concurrent programming primitives and provide you with more high-level constructs?

I tried [QtConcurrent](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Threads/QtConcurrent) which provides you with nice MapReduce functionality but it is heavily biased towards concurrent computation using Qt so it's not a good choice if you don't want to use Qt.

Are there any other similar libraries? What do people use here?

Thanks for your help in advance,
sneg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several choices:

[ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) which provides some [concurrency constructs](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-papers.html#concurrency)

Intel [Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

[boost::threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html)

[OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/)

[Qt Threading libraries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads.html)

Answer (score 4):

Morendil's suggestion (CSP - communicating sequential processes) is truly interesting to take a look at - it's a very different view of threading and one that works well once you wrap your head around it.  I first encountered it in the rather esoteric Occam language for Transputers, but the idea has stuck with me.

A more conventional idea: [boost::threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) work quite well for building thread-based concurrent programs.  It's quite low level though.

[OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) is at a higher level than threads and also quite well-supported.

Comment: Yes,  you're right - with OpenMP the developer doesn't have to worry about actual threads.  It's a parallelism library rather than a threading library.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), which has a [C++](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/c++csp/) implementation. Way different from Java's threading primitives, though.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565137/multithreaded-job-queue-manager) along with the answers can probably help you a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's Threading Building Blocks is great for introducing concurrency at the level of individual data-parallel loops, and it takes care of managing threads and allocating work automagically. It can be used in similar ways to OpenMP, but without the need for explicit compiler support.